# Java:Using an Actionlistener in one class that refrences a variable in another class

Tags: java

I have a JTextField and a button in a class called Main.  I have an ActionListener in another class called Action.  I want the ActionListener to be able to refrence the JTextField.  I keep getting a null pointer exception.  I want to keep the JTextField and ActionListener seperate.  I am going to be having many ActionListeners and it would be easier for me to organize it this way.

```
public class Main  {

    public JTextField text;

    public JTextField getText(){
        return this.text;
    }

public  static void main(String[] args) {

        Main main=new Main();
        main.blah();
    }

public  void blah(){

    JFrame myWindow=new JFrame("ff");
    myWindow.setSize(500,500);
    myWindow.setVisible(true);
    myWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    text=new JTextField(10);
    JLabel lengthL = new JLabel("Enter a number",SwingConstants.CENTER  );
    JButton button=new JButton("Click button");
    myWindow.getContentPane();
    myWindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));
    myWindow.add(lengthL);
    myWindow.add(text);
    myWindow.add(button);

    Action hand=new Action();
    button.addActionListener(hand);
}
}



public  class Action  implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Main main=new Main();
        double length=Double.parseDouble(main.text.getText());
        System.out.println(length);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not pass the JTextField when you create the ActionListener, like so:

```
public  class Action  implements ActionListener{
    private JTextField text;

    public Action(JTextField text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        double length=Double.parseDouble(text.getText());
        System.out.println(length);
    }
}

//in Main:
public void blah(){
    JFrame myWindow=new JFrame("ff");
    myWindow.setSize(500,500);
    myWindow.setVisible(true);
    myWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    text=new JTextField(10);
    JLabel lengthL = new JLabel("Enter a number",SwingConstants.CENTER  );
    JButton button=new JButton("Click button");
    myWindow.getContentPane();
    myWindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));
    myWindow.add(lengthL);
    myWindow.add(text);
    myWindow.add(button);

    Action hand=new Action(text);  //change this line
    button.addActionListener(hand);
}
```

Comment: Because he wants : *..to keep the JTextField and ActionListener seperate...*

Comment: @OscarRyz - Giving the ActionListener a reference to a `Main` instance is not keeping them separate, if anything it creates a greater dependency because the ActionListener is only useful with text-fields associated with that `Main` class.  By passing in a text-field, the ActionListener is more reusable, which is more keeping in spirit with what keeping the classes separate is supposed to accomplish.

Comment: +1 @aroth I'm not sure how good would be to create a coupling between the textfield and the listener, but I agree with you about my solution is not much better  @clay123 You should mark aroth answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

*I keep getting a null pointer exception*

That's because you're creating a new `Main` instance when you handle the event:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Main main=new Main();
    ...
```

You should better have the action a reference of the container class ( Main ) and a method to access that textfield value:

```
   Main aMain; 
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    this.aMain.getText();
    ....
```

Or even better:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       double lenght = this.main.getValue();// returns double 
       ...
```

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested but I am still getting a null pointer

Comment: @clay: then you're doing it wrong, but for us to say more, you'll have to show how you're trying to implement Oscar's suggestions and where the NPE. We can't read minds.